# Qt Deployment for Mac, configuring executable inside bundle

Tags: qt, macos, deployment

I was previously stuck on trying to build a Qt project that held the Qt libraries in the app bundle. I noticed the problem was that the executable inside the MacOS directory did not have execute permissions. Is there any way configure the build where the executable in the MacOS folder contains execute permissions by default?

Comment: Never seen that, the executable usually has the correct permissions.

Comment: @user337786 : You should accept answers to your questions, otherwise people won't bother trying help you !

Answer (score 0):

You generally never care about exe permission when you build your exec from QtCreator. The main problem is attach all Qt frameworks for mac in your app bundle(solve by macdeployqt)

If you try to recompile from scratch you app, do you have always the same permission problem ?