# Submit MacOS X application to AppleStore from Qt project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, qt, app-store

**Context**

I have to submit a MacOSX application to the AppStore. App was generated by Qt.

I'm using OSX 10.11 and Xcode 7.0 beta (7A121l)

**What I have tried**

I have created a MacOSX app with Qt that I have to submit to the AppStore

When I generate the `.app`file with Qt, it runs pretty well. I don't know how to create a binary to upload with Application Loader for Mac so I have exported that Qt project to a Xcode project using the following command

`qmake -spec macx-xcode Myproject.pro`

And it creates a Xcode project for me.

**Problem**
When I compile that app inside Xcode, some frameworks are not found.

```
Ld Debug/track.app/Contents/MacOS/track normal x86_64
    cd /Users/User/development/projects/track/track_desktop
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/User/development/projects/track/track_desktop/Debug -L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -L/Users/User/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -F/Users/User/development/projects/track/track_desktop/Debug -F/Users/User/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/User/development/projects/track/track_desktop/track.build/Debug/track.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/track.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -F/System/Library/Frameworks -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-rpath,/Users/User/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -F/Users/User/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -framework Carbon -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework QtNetwork -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/User/development/projects/track/track_desktop/track.build/Debug/track.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/track_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/User/development/projects/track/track_desktop/Debug/track.app/Contents/MacOS/track


ld: framework not found Carbon
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And also: `DiskArbitration`, `IOKit`, `OpenGL` and `AGL`

**Conclusion**

I think that qmake hadn't created the linker paths correctly.

**Question**

How can I link that libraries to my Xcode project in order to compile and to generate my binary?

These answers and questions don't help me:
[Qt Mac Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442358/qt-mac-deployment) > I have done that
[Qt Mac OS Deployment - You must supply an Apple ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642246/qt-mac-os-deployment-you-must-supply-an-apple-id) -> He didn't explain how to do it
[Qt Deployment for Mac, configuring executable inside bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433933/qt-deployment-for-mac-configuring-executable-inside-bundle)

Comment: Just search SO for "qt mac deployment", this question has been asked and answered many, many times before.

Comment: I think he is asking how to link the frameworks